# end() is not a function in a Node Mocha testing

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js

I'm trying to test some services of my Nodejs API with mocha:

```
exports.getModelts = function () {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    Modelt.find(function (err, modelts) {
      if (err) {
        return reject(err);
      }
      return resolve(modelts);
    });
  });
}
```

And the test:

```
it('returns expected payload', function (done) {
  service
    .getModelts()
    .end(function (err, res) {
      expect(res.body.length).to.eql(6);
      expect(res.body[0].text).to.eql('Todo 1');

      done();
    });
});
```

I get the error:

```
TypeError: service.getModelts(...).end is not a function
```

Any help would be appreciatte.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`.end()` is a part of `supertest`, but you're not using that in your test (or in the method that you are testing).

Instead, you should test inside a `.then`, because your method returns a Promise:

```
it('returns expected payload', function() {
  return service
    .getModelts()
    .then(function(res) {
      // I expect that the following tests will fail,
      // because they assume that `res` is a `supertest`
      // response, and your method returns a Mongoose
      // query result
      expect(res.body.length).to.eql(6);
      expect(res.body[0].text).to.eql('Todo 1');
    });
});
```

(also notice how the test function *returns* the Promise chain, and doesn't use `done`; this is because Mocha supports promises out of the box, and mixing promises with callbacks can cause problems).

Comment: Still the same TypeError: service.getModelts(...).then is not a function

Comment: It returns a promise, and promises should have a `.then` method. If that's not the case, there's something else wrong in your code.